# Is this an effective while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here is an assignment:

"Let's say you are given a number, a, and you want to find its
square root. One way to do that is to start with a very rough guess about
the answer, x0, and then improve the guess using the following formula
x1 = (x0 + a/x0)/2

For example, if we want to find the square root of 9, and we start with x0 = 6,
then x1 = (6 + 9/6)/2 = 15/4 = 3.75, which is closer.
We can repeat the procedure, using x1 to calculate x2, and so on. In this
case, x2 = 3.075 and x3 = 3.00091. So that is converging very quickly on the
right answer(which is 3).

Write a method called `squareRoot` that takes a double as a parameter and
that returns an approximation of the square root of the parameter, using this
technique. You may not use `Math.sqrt`.

As your initial guess, you should use a/2. Your method should iterate until
it gets two consecutive estimates that differ by less than 0.0001; in other
words, until the absolute value is less than 0.0001. You can use
`Math.abs` to calculate the absolute value."

This is exercise meant to practice while loop. As you see I did the assignment, I think it works ? But I am not sure how did I come to solution ? In other words, what should I improve here ? Is there any other way to enter the loop differently ? How to name variables more appropriately ? And lastly, is my approach good or bad here ?

```
public class squareRoot {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(squareRoot(192.0));
    }

    public static double squareRoot(double a){

        double gs = a/2; //guess
        double ig = (gs + (a/gs))/2; //improving guess

        double ig1 = (ig + (a/ig))/2; //one more improving guess, ig1

        while (Math.abs((ig-ig1)) > 0.0001){  //with ig and ig1, I am entering the loop
            ig = (ig1 + (a/ig1))/2;
            ig1 = (ig + (a/ig))/2;  //ig1 has to be less then ig
        }
        return ig1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can name your variables whatever you want. Write some test cases if you are unsure about the function of the code

Comment: If you need to write a comment to say what an abbreviation means, you probably shouldn't be using an abbreviation. Call the variable `guess`.  Long names are better than unclear short names.

Comment: And you see how `ig = (gs + (a/gs))/2` and `ig1 = (ig + (a/ig))/2` are duplicated inside and outside of the loop? That means you should probably be using a `do...while` loop instead. You'd need to rewrite it a bit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is nearly correct.

Let's talk about variables first. IMO, you should use full names for variables instead of acronyms. Use `guess` instead of `gs`. Use `improvedGuess` instead of `ig` etc.

Now that's out of the way we can see where your problem lies. For the while loop to finish, two consecutive guesses' difference must be less than 0.0001. However, here you are only comparing the 1st and 2nd guesses, the 3rd and 4th guesses, the 5th and 6th guesses etc. What if the 4th and 5th guesses' difference is less than 0.0001? Your loop won't stop. Instead, it returns the value of the 6th guess. Although it is more accurate, it does not fulfill the requirement.

Here's what I've come up with

```
public static double squareRoot(double a){

    double guess = a/2;
    double improvedGuess = (guess + (a/guess))/2;

    while (Math.abs((guess - improvedGuess)) > 0.0001){
        guess = improvedGuess;
        improvedGuess = (guess + (a/guess))/2;
    }
    return improvedGuess;
}
```

Comment: I knew that something was going on with my code, but I couldn't put it into words like you did! Your way is a bit better, I guess :)

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark @Miljan

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Solution

```
  private static double squareRoot(double a){

    double x0= a/2;
    while (true) {
        double x1 = (x0 + a / x0) / 2;

        if (Math.abs(x1 - x0) < 0.0001) {
            break;
        }
        x0=x1;
    }
    return x0;
}
```

Comment: It is really ugly to use a 'while(true)' and a 'break;' within the loop. You should create a temporary boolean and use proper named variables.

Comment: You are absolutely right but this question from "Think Java" book. I named variables according to variables in the exercise from the book.